# A more common term for "rabbit cold."

Tags: terminology, lolita

I've been quoting *Lolita* (as well as *Don Juan*, *Man and Superman*, *Pygmalion*, *Tom Jones*, and various Mark Twain's witticisms) for a while now; some people might be annoyed by this, but I don't care anymore, for reasons that should be obvious to some people here):

From *Lolita* by Vladimir Nabokov:

> She sat right in the focus of my incandescent anger. The fog of all lust had been swept away leaving nothing but this dreadful lucidity. Oh, she had changed! Her complexion was now that of any vulgar untidy highschool girl who applies shared cosmetics with grubby fingers to an unwashed face and does not mind what soiled texture, what pustulate epidermis comes in contact with her skin. Its smooth tender bloom had been so lovely in former days, so bright with tears, when I used to roll, in play, her tousled head on my knee. A coarse flush had now replaced that innocent fluorescence. What was locally known as a **"rabbit cold**" had painted with flaming pink the edges of her contemptuous nostrils. As in terror I lowered my gaze, it mechanically slid along the underside of her tensely stretched bare thigh—how polished and muscular her legs had grown!

The way it's dashingly described, the condition is instantly recognizable in the sentence (let's give the author that, he is an artist, not just a linguist).

But. Is there a more common term for it?

[image]

**Addendum:**

"Locally known" would mean New England, or, to be more precise, Massachusetts, where the novel's "Beardsley School for Girls" is located, according to some reputable sources, including, but not limited to, the fellow who authored *The Annotated Lolita* (a volume that includes the novel's text and an index and comments whose length exceeds that of the novel).

A bright gal published an essay on the web in which she claimed she had definitely gone to the school that is described in the novel. The essay includes this photo:

[image]

In the French translation of the novel the "rabbit cold" is referred to as "*le rhume des lapins*" (courtesy of @Graffito): word-for-word, and just as puzzling as the original. The Russian translation of the same novel (penned by Nabokov himself) has it as "кроличья простуда", which, I'm told, is the exact same thing, and a quick google search on it turns up the exact same useless slew of references to sick rabbits and various methods of treating them as the original.

Comment: I had to look this up and I still don't know what it's referring to.

Comment: @SomethingDark: Oh, come on. Look at the picture.

Comment: Well now that you've added a picture, sure. But google "rabbit cold" and you'll get a bunch of people asking if their rabbits are sick. http://i.imgur.com/7zmRhLn.png

Comment: @SomethingDark: Well, if Google had an answer, I wouldn't be posting the question here, would I. "Locally known" really means "locally," or "very locally," some Midwestern town: Nabokov was very anal about such things. The condition, on the other hand, is pretty common. Which is why I asked. Since I don't know, while you, or someone else, might. Sheesh.

Comment: You could have at least mentioned in your question that it was illness-related. The passage you provided made me think of face paint, not a stuffy nose.

Comment: @SomethingDark: Shouldn't the word _cold_ in _rabbit cold_ have given you some clues? Look. It's nothing against you. I like you. I do have a soft spot for Virginia, for various reasons. But the way folks totally refuse to give anything _any_ thought drives me nuts.

Comment: With Google being as unhelpful as it was, I figured it was a figure of speech. Red herrings are neither red, nor herrings.

Comment: @SomethingDark: I _know_ you're doing this on purpose, but, fine, okay, have it your way, I'm expanding the damn quote. You win.

Comment: @SomethingDark: On second thoughts, I'm not. It's more subtle than that. This "rabbit cold" business is more than just a cold. Some people, and especially young girls, have permanently pink nostrils.

Comment: The French translation is: *L'inflammation que l'on nomme ici "le rhume des lapins" avait peint de rose vif le bord de ses narines dédaigneuses*. What would literrally be translated to English as: *the inflammation that is called here "rabbit cold" has painted ...*. I suppose that "rabbit cold" is a littteral translation of a Russian expression for the effect of a cold.

Comment: @Graffito: It isn't.

Comment: There is a vague possibility that he's describing the effects of frostbite.

Comment: Probably just *red nose*.

Answer (score 5):

***[Runny nose](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhinorrhea)*** is an alternative expression;
[image]

Rhinorrhea or rhinorrhoea is a condition where the nasal cavity is filled with a significant amount of mucus fluid. ***The condition, commonly known as a runny nose,*** occurs relatively frequently. Rhinorrhea is a common symptom of allergies or certain diseases, such as the common cold or hay fever.

(Wikipedia)

Comment: Okay, now I _have to_ expand the quote a little.

Comment: This seems logical.  When you have a runny nose, it has a tendency to get pink(like a bunny's) from all the wiping, AND the constant sniffing (to halt the flow) emulates the characteristic twitchy nose of a rabbit.

Answer (score 4):

It could be that Lolita was showing the first signs of **[rosacea](http://www.webmd.com/skin-problems-and-treatments/features/rosacea-more-than-red-face)**

> **Rosacea starts as redness on the cheeks, nose, chin, or forehead** (and less often on the neck, scalp, chest, or ears). At first, rosacea comes and goes. After a while, the redness deepens and lasts longer. Visible blood vessels appear in the skin. If not treated, pimples and bumps develop. The nose may become large and bumpy as tissue builds up. And rosacea sometimes affects the eyes, making them irritated, watery, and bloodshot.

Source: WebMD.com

[image]

There is another, very similar, skin ailment called **couperose** that mimics the symptoms of a reddish nose and flushed cheeks

> The following list represents the differences between Couperose and Rosacea:
>
> - **Couperose skin is usually found on those with very pale complexions living in cold, harsh climates.** The skin appears red with broken capillaries, dry and tight, but is not inflamed.
> - **A flushed or blushing look is often a symptom of couperose skin**.
> - Meanwhile, Rosacea is marked by excessive inflammation, facial flushing and bumps on the skin.
> - Rosacea may be accompanied by a burning, stinging sensation that is similar to sunburn. The skin may simply feel warm. Couperose skin does not experience this sensation.
> - Skin that is Couperose is not subjected to the acne-like pimples that are found in some cases of Rosacea.
> - Sun exposure, extreme temperatures and lifestyle factors such as smoking and alcohol consumption will trigger or exacerbate couperose.
> - Some Rosacea sufferers may experience Couperose skin as a symptom.

And, I'm sorry to disappoint the OP but I found no instances that supported Humbert's claim that "rabbit nose" was a vernacular expression from Ramsdale in New Hampshire. The only examples of "rabbit cold" I found on Google Books, which did not refer to rabbits feeling the cold, were related to Nabokov's novel. If it is a dialectal expression, it has either faded away or it never existed, a neologism that Nabokov created for literary purposes.